Prenex-normal form theorem for many sorted logic
I am looking for a reference that contains an analogous of the first-order prenex normal form theorem for many sorts.

@AlexKruckman that's helpful, please feel free to post it as an answer

@AlexKruckman: if you do take up the OP's suggestion to post your comment as an answer, it would be useful to explain what goes wrong when you allow empty sorts (it took me 10 minutes to work it out).

The status of prenex normal form in many-sorted logic depends on whether your semantics requires all sorts to be non-empty or not. But in either case, there's not really anything new to say about the many-sorted setting.
If you require all sorts to be non-empty, the statement and proof of the prenex normal form theorem are identical to the single-sorted case.
If you don't require all sorts to be non-empty, then not every formula is equivalent to one in prenex form. For example, let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be sorts, and let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be predicates of type $S_1$ and $S_2$, respectively.
Consider the sentence $\varphi\colon ((\exists x_1:S_1)\, P_1(x_1))\lor ((\exists x_2:S_2) \,P_2(x_2))$.
Let $A_1$ be a structure in which $S_1^A$ is empty and $S_2^A$ contains a single element which satisfies $P_2$. Then $A_1\models \varphi$, but $S_1^A$ is empty, so $\varphi$ is not equivalent to any formula beginning with a quantifier $(\exists y: S_1)$.
Let $A_2$ be a structure in which $S_1^A$ is empty and $S_2^A$ contains a single element which does not satisfy $P_2$. Then $A_1\not\models \varphi$, but $S_1^A$ is empty, so $\varphi$ is not equivalent to any formula beginning with a quantifier $(\forall y: S_1)$.
Let $A_3$ be a structure in which $S_2^A$ is empty and $S_1^A$ contains a single element which satisfies $P_1$. Then $A_3\models \varphi$, but $S_2^A$ is empty, so $\varphi$ is not equivalent to any formula beginning with a quantifier $(\exists y: S_2)$.
Let $A_4$ be a structure in which $S_2^A$ is empty and $S_1^A$ contains a single element which does not satisfy $P_1$. Then $A_1\not\models \varphi$, but $S_2^A$ is empty, so $\varphi$ is not equivalent to any formula beginning with a quantifier $(\forall y: S_2)$.
Also, the only quantifier-free sentences in this language are $\top$ and $\bot$, and $\varphi$ is not equivalent to either of these, since it is true in $A_1$ but false in $A_2$.
Thus $\varphi$ is not equivalent to any sentence in prenex form.
